# Related to card view patterns

Tags: android, xml, android-cardview

[image: Card View]

I know that they are not `Card View` in the picture(i am using this picture just for reference to make you guys understand what I'm saying). But, I want to create a `card view` making some angle.

Comment: This should be a good starting point. Edit it to fit your needs.
http://www.tutorialsee.com/viewpager/how-make-android-carousel-cardview-view-pager

Comment: That is literally just an image. Try PhotoShop

Answer (score 0):

Didn't you try **android:rotation** ?

It's available since api level 11.

```
  <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/card_view"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:rotation="90"
       card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/info_text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```